# content navigation help

Tags: html, typo3, typoscript

I'm working on a content navigation in typoscript. These requirements should be accomplished:

- show the current node at the top -> is done!
- show all child nodes of the current page -> is done!
- if there are no child nodes, show last treelevel with with the current page active - not done yet!

For the last point, I need help. I tried to do something with `[treelevel = 2]` to control the navigation on the last treelevel, but nothing happened. Don't know why but the treelevel-condition won't work for me. Another problem is, sometimes the last treelevel is on 2nd level, sometimes on 3rd...

any ideas?

This is the typoscript so far:

```
temp.leftCol = COA
temp.leftCol {

   5 = HTML
   5.value = <ul class="contentNav">

   ### show current page on top
   10 = TEXT
   10.typolink {
      parameter.data = TSFE:id
   }

   10 {
      wrap = <li class="title">|</li>
      data = leveltitle:2
      if {
         isTrue.numRows {
            table = pages
         }
      }
   }

   ### content navigation: show subpages
   20 = HMENU
   20.entryLevel = -1

   20.1 = TMENU
   20.1 {
      noBlur = 1
      NO = 1
      CUR = 1
      expAll = 1
   }

   20.1.NO {
      wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
      stdWrap.wrap = |
      allStdWrap.insertData = 1
   }


   20.1.CUR {
      wrapItemAndSub = <li class="on">|</li>
      stdWrap.wrap = |
      allStdWrap.insertData = 1
   }

   20.1.wrap = |</ul>
}
```

Comment: Are you aware of the `IFSUB`, `ACTIFSUB`, and `CURIFSUB` [states](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/references/doc_core_tsref/4.1.0/view/10/2/)? I find it hard to believe that `treeLevel` conditions will help you out here :-S

Comment: What I'm trying to say is: perhaps you can replace your current `20.1.CUR` with `20.1.CURIFSUB` and then add a new `20.1.CUR` to handle the last case.

Comment: I'm aware of these states. But I guess I have to work with the `entryLevel` attribute, to change the navig's look in the last treelevel, or I'm wrong? Don't know a way to do this with the `IFSUB`, `ACTIFSUB` and `CURIFSUB` states...

Comment: Pretty sure I've misunderstood the question, then :(

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by this exactly?

if there are no child nodes, show last treelevel with with the current page active - not done yet!

As I understand it, it could be either

1) Letssay that there are 10 pages on level 1, and every one of those pages except page 7 have 3 subpages each. And letssay page 7 has no subpages. Then, when I go to page 7, it will display page 7 as active, but display subpages from page 6 (the "show last treelevel") under it.

or

2) When user navigates to page 7, it displays page 7 as active, and subpages for whatever page the user has been right before that? So that for example, if I navigate to page 2 first, and then go to page 7, I will see page 7 as active, and subpages for page 2.

Comment: My question is not clear enough, Im sorry for that. Example 1 is very close, but my need is more easier: 

if you click on a page which has subpages, it shows the page as active above and underneath the subpages. if you go on a page without subpages, it stay's at the current treelevel and show the page as active.

I've made a temporary solution yet with absolute paths, which is not a good solution, but it's what I need. let's have a look to the navigation at the left: http://www.pksbb.ch/index.php?id=36 (click on the item “Zusätzlicher Einkauf" and you will se what I mean. 

thank you.